# s:Group and loading image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

take a look at the following class

```
public class CanvasHolder extends SpriteVisualElement {
    ....

    public function draw(filename: String):void {
        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(.....);
        loader.load(request);
        addChild(loader);
    }
}
```

When it used in mxml as follows

```
<ctw:CanvasHolder id="holder"/>
```

image is loaded. But when I try to insert it into scroller

```
<s:Group id="canvasGroup" width="400" height="100%" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <ctw:CanvasHolder id="holder"/>
</s:Group>
```

image is not shown. Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: instead of adding the loader why you cant try drawing the loaded bitmap over the sprite visual element graphics, and also make sure that your image is loaded correctly.

Comment: Thank you for response! And what the profit in drawing bitmap over graphics? The image is loaded correctly (that should not depend on s:Group element).

Comment: the code i give below works fine for me, thanks hope  that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    import mx.binding.utils.BindingUtils;

    import spark.core.SpriteVisualElement;

    public class CanvasLoader extends SpriteVisualElement
    {
        public function CanvasLoader()
        {
            super();
        }


        public function draw(url: String):void {
            var loader:Loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            loader.load(request);
        }


        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var bitmap:Bitmap = event.target.content as Bitmap;
            addChild(bitmap);
        }

        private function onError(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
        {
            trace(event.text);
        }

    }
}
```

and inside your main mxml add this

```
holder.draw("http://yourdomain.com/image.jpg");
```